# how to reuse variables across different playbook/tasks using set_stats in Ansible

Tags: ansible, statistics, reusability, ansible-tower

I am trying to reuse the ***test_stat*** variable in *testing_todelete_stat.yml*. I have defined this variable as **set_stats** in the file *testing_todelete_task.yml*
but I am getting the following **error message** when running debug task.

what am I doing wrong?

**Output:**

```
FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. 
 The error was: 'test_stat' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in ****/testing_todelete_stat.yml': line 7, column 7
PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************localhost                  : ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

***testing_todelete_task.yml***

```
- name: check google
 uri:
   url: http://www.google.com
   return_content: yes
 register: this

- set_fact:  
   this_local: "{{ this.url }}"   

- set_stats:
   data:
     test_stat: "{{ this_local }}"
```

***testing_todelete_stat.yml***

```
- name: PLaybook to check set_stats
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks: 
    - name: include task
      include_tasks: testing_todelete_task.yml
    - name: content of set_stats
      debug:
        msg: "{{ test_stat }}"
```

Comment: stats are not variables. You misunderstood what they are. Custom stats can be aggregated or replaced, accumulated per host or globally and will be displayed at the end of your playbook run if you [set the proper config or env var](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/set_stats_module.html#notes).

Comment: In the above case, you can simply use the fact you previously set, even directly your registered var directly.

Comment: You can access this_local fact from hostvars.. `hostvars[localhost]['this_local']` or hostvars[inventory_hostname]['this_local']` in your testing_todelete_task.yml

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @[Krishna Reddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12821102/krishna-reddy) works for me: `hostvars['localhost']['this_local']`

To add more information about **set_stats**, you can get the value of those variables directly using workflow in Ansible Tower/AWX. This information is taken from one playbook to another through what are known as **Artifacts** .

Modifying the initial example it would be as follows using workflow:

Playbook1:

```
    - name: PLaybook to generate set_stats
      hosts: localhost
      gather_facts: true
      tasks:
        - name: check google
          uri:
            url: http://www.google.com
            return_content: yes
          register: this

        - set_fact:  
            this_local: "{{ this.url }}"   

        - set_stats:
            data:
              test_stat: "{{ this_local }}"

        - name: debug set fact
          debug:
            msg: "{{ this.url}}"
```

Playbook2:

```
    - name: PLaybook to check set_stats
      hosts: localhost
      gather_facts: true
      tasks:   
        - name: content of set_stats
          debug:
            msg: "{{ test_stat }}"
```

Result:

```
PLAY [PLaybook to check set_stats] *********************************************
TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
ok: [localhost]
TASK [content of set_stats] ****************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "http://www.google.com"
}
PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```